# How do I create a Dart const List at runtime

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use actions in the flutter local notifications package.
The actions array in the package is defined as

`final List<AndroidNotificationAction>? actions;`

My problem is that my actions are only available at runtime, so my code is

```
const List<AndroidNotificationAction> androidActions = [];
androidActions.add(AndroidNotificationAction("action1", someRunTimeData)); 
...
AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id', 'your channel name',                                                                                       
  actions: androidActions,      
...
```

... which throws a runtime error "Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list".

If I remove the const and replace with a final, I get a compilation error "Const variables must be initialized with a constant value.Try changing the initializer to be a constant expression. dart (const_initialized_with_non_constant_value) "

**So how do I provide a const to the package, using runtime data?**

ref...
https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/AndroidNotificationDetails/actions.html

Comment: `const` means a compile-time constant.  By definition it cannot be set at runtime.  If removing the `const` from the `androidActions` declaration gives you an error message, then you're using `androidActions` somewhere else in a `const` context.  Remove `const` from those other places.

Comment: const in runtime is final